# How can make a for loop not past NA when the index runs out?

Tags: r

```
xlen <- 50                                          # Length
xGRU <- seq(1, 2723, by = xlen)                     # Start ID
xjob <- 36                                          # Numbe of Jobs per Joblist

# List of all run Commands
runcommands <- paste("TESTTHIS", xGRU, xlen , '-r d', '-m', sep=" ")
runcommands <- append(head(runcommands, -1),
                           paste("TESTTHIS", tail(xGRU,1), 11723%%xlen ,
                                 '-r d', '-m', sep=" "))

for(i in seq(1, length(runcommands), by = xjob)){
  jobfileName <- paste0('data_raw/joblist_', i, ".txt")
  cat(paste(runcommands[i:(i+xjob-1)]), file=jobfileName, append=TRUE, sep = "\n")
}
```

But the last file that is created has `NAs` in it. How can I ensure that the `for loop` doesn't write out NA when the index runs out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `?lapply` and simply drop the `NA` objects from each `vector` prior to writing

```
lapply(seq_along(runcommands), function(i){
    # create a new file inside of the temporary directory
    # for help see ?sprintf
    fl <- sprintf('data_raw/joblist_%s.txt', i)
    # cleaned up your seq chunk a bit, and then the key is to remove
    # the NA items prior to writing to file
    job_list <- runcommands[seq(i, i + (xjob - 1))] %>% .[!is.na(.)]

    stringi::stri_write_lines(job_list, sep = "\n", fname = fl)
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You could prevent this from happening by being more rigorous with your use of indices in the `cat` function call. But as a quick workaround you can do this:

```
for(i in seq(1, length(runcommands), by = xjob)){
  jobfileName <- paste0('~/SO_posts/joblist_', i, ".txt")
  cat(paste(na.omit(runcommands[i:(i+xjob-1)])), file=jobfileName, append=TRUE, sep = "\n")
}
```